# Laravel returning only single column

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my database I have categories and sizes, they have a table to match them together called category_sizes which looks like:

[image: table fields screenshot]

I want to get an array with all `size_id` where `category_id = 4` so I did:

```php
$catSizes = CategorySize::where('category_id', 4)->value('size_id');
return($catSizes);
```

But it returns one result only. How can I get an array with all size_ids so I can use it later in a `where_in` statement.

I also tried pluck but this gives also just one row.

```php
$catSizes = CategorySize::where('category_id', 4)->pluck('size_id');
dd($catSizes);
```

My CategoySize model

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CategorySize extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'category_sizes';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DB::table('category_sizes')->where('category_id', 4)->get('size_id');
```

Or:

```
DB::table('category_sizes')->select('size_id')->where('category_id', 4)->get();
```

Comment: Just for my interest: Is there a reason why you suggested `DB::table` instead of using the model?

Comment: @Peh, I guess it's possible to use Eloquent here too (`->pivot` and -`>withPivot` methods): https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many - but I couldn't post working Eloquent code without testing (I don't have enough time for this right now, sorry).